# Como visualizar varias datas pre-selecionadas no datepicker jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

Meu código não mostra as datas selecionadas no calendário ,veja tenho um array de datas mas não mostra.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var array = ["2015/05/03", "2015/05/13", "2015/05/23"];

    $j("#Data").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            if ($j.inArray($j.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date), array) > -1) {
                return [false, "", "Booked out"];
            } else {
                return [true, '', "available"];
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Repara que as datas que tens na `array` estão no formato `yy/mm/dd` e no código estás a pedir ao datepicker para formatar com `dd/mm/yy`.

Muda para `formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date)` e já vai funcionar.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usrbo7fe/

Notas:

- repara que estás à procura de um ID que começa com letra grande `D`. Verifica que o ID no HTML está igual.
- nota que as datas que bloqueias estão em maio, tens de andar para a frente para as ver (pois estamos em abril)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: estou recebendo agora datas nesse formato e estar dando erro ["2015-04-10T00:00:00","2015-04-11T00:00:00"]

Comment: @HansMiller queres dizer que as datas dentro de `var array` estão nesse formato e não no formato que colocaste na pergunta?

Comment: sim! teria como formatá-las para ficar nesse modulo?

Comment: @HansMiller sim, faz assim: https://jsfiddle.net/usrbo7fe/1/

Comment: cara gera o datepicker mas nao destaca as datas no calendario

Comment: @HansMiller ok, então podes ser mais claro: de onde vem `array`? é isto que queres: https://jsfiddle.net/usrbo7fe/2/ ?